# Use I18n translation messages from SFC when using Vue.extend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-i18n

I'm working on an app I'm migrate to VueJS so some parts are using old jQuery code.

So I'm trying to append an VueJS component using jQuery, so I made

```
import copyToClipboard from '../components/_base/VCopyToClipboard';

const CopyToClipboard = Vue.extend(copyToClipboard);
  $(event.currentTarget).find('.dns-challenge-row').each((index, element) =>     {
    const component = new CopyToClipboard({
      propsData: {
        targetId: $(element).find('code').attr('id'),
      },
    }).$mount();

    $(element).append(component.$el);
  });
```

Everything is working BUT when I go on the page where this component is appended, i18n return an error

> Cannot translate the value of keypath 'tooltip.default'. Use the value of keypath as default.

FYI my translation messages are directly defined inside my SFC using the `i18n` keyword

```
i18n: {
  messages: {
    en: {
      tooltip: {
        default: 'Copy content',
        success: 'Copied',
      },
    },
    fr: {
      tooltip: {
        default: 'Copier le contenu',
        success: 'Copié',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

and I use then directly inside the SFC using `this.$t('tooltip.default')`

My i18n is import like the docs say but is loaded after the `vue.js` I use to create my component.

```
import {
  Vue,
} from './vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';
import en from '../../translations/en';
import fr from '../../translations/fr';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

export default new VueI18n({
  locale: document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].getAttribute('lang'),
  messages: {
    en,
    fr,
  },
});
```

The `vue.js` file is the the file where I put all my `Vue.use()` definitions, my routern, other stuff and is used to create the Vue instance inside another file

```
vueSetup(new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    ...
  },
  i18n: i18n,
  router: router,
  store: store,
}));
```

Do you have an idea to solve this?

I tried to load i18n before the vue component without success and I saw a lot of GitHub issues with this error but not like my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just import and add `i18n` instance to the new component instance

```
const CopyToClipboard = Vue.extend(copyToClipboard);
  $(event.currentTarget).find('.dns-challenge-row').each((index, element) =>     {
    const component = new CopyToClipboard({
      i18n: i18n,
      propsData: {
        targetId: $(element).find('code').attr('id'),
      },
    }).$mount();

    $(element).append(component.$el);
});
```